# Non-PHP Proxy Possible? Or script hidable?

Tags: php, proxy, block

The place i am trying to bypass blocks all php proxy scripts automatically. I need a proxy that doesn't use php, if that is possible? Or at least a way to disguise the script?

Comment: I wonder how this site knows you're using a PHP proxy...

Answer (score 1):

Install a [Perl proxy](http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/) then.